# Deriving the *spectral decomposition* of a self-adjoint bounded operator in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

**Notation**: Let $a,b,m,M\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $a<m\leq M<b$, and let $A$ be an operator satisfying $mI\leq A\leq MI$. Let  $K[a,b]$ is the set of all piecewise continuous bounded functions which are monotone decreasing limits of continuous functions.

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely functions of operators. In the text, the author gives the following paragraph:

> **Paragraph A**: We are now ready to derive the *spectral decomposition* of a self-adjoint bounded operator in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.
>
> Consider the function
> $$
> e_\lambda(t):= \begin{cases}
>                  1, & t\leq\lambda \\
>                  0, & t>\lambda.    \tag{1}
>                \end{cases}
> $$
> Obviously $e_\lambda(t)\in K[a,b]$ and define $E_\lambda:=e_\lambda(A)$. Then, $E_\lambda^2=E_\lambda$ since $e_\lambda(t)\cdot e_\lambda(t)=e_\lambda(t)$ and $E_\lambda$ is self-adjoint (since $e_\lambda$ is a real valued-function).

This paragraph is a bit confusing to me. For starters, how is $E_\lambda:=e_\lambda(A)$ *actually* defined? Using $(1)$, I, at first, though it would be defined as
$$
E_\lambda=e_\lambda(A):= \begin{cases}
                 1, & A\leq\lambda \\
                 0, & A>\lambda.    \tag{2}
               \end{cases}
$$
However, neither $A\leq\lambda$ nor $A>\lambda$ makes sense (at least I don't think so). Therefore, I figured it must be defined as
$$
E_\lambda=e_\lambda(A):= \begin{cases}
                 1, & A\leq\lambda I \\
                 0, & A>\lambda I.    \tag{3}
               \end{cases}
$$
Now this, of course, makes sense (at least I think so), but is it correct?

Moving on from that, I don't see how $E_\lambda^2=E_\lambda$ is implied from $e_\lambda(t)\cdot e_\lambda(t)=e_\lambda(t)$. There is a previous result, I'll call it a lemma, that says:

> **Lemma 1**:  If $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in K[a,b]$ with $\varphi_1\geq0$ and $\varphi_2\geq0$, then $(\varphi_1\cdot\varphi_2)(A)=\varphi_1(A)\cdot\varphi_2(A)$.

Therefore, since $e_\lambda\in K[a,b]$ and $e_\lambda\geq0$, we have by **Lemma 1** that
$(e_\lambda\cdot e_\lambda)(A)=e_\lambda(A)\cdot e_\lambda(A)$. It's obvious that $e_\lambda(A)\cdot e_\lambda(A)=e_\lambda(A)=E_\lambda$. So what the author must be saying is that $e_\lambda(A)\cdot e_\lambda(A)=E_\lambda^2$...how? I though that $E_\lambda^2$ is a composition of functions as follows $E_\lambda^2=E_\lambda(E_\lambda)=e_\lambda(e_\lambda)$.

I believe I'm just missing something really simple here, but it's not making sense.

---

**EDIT**(Defining $\varphi(A)$):

Let $\varphi(t)\in K[a,b]$. Then there is a monotone decreasing sequence of continuous real functions that converge to $\varphi(t)$. It's not hard to see, via the Weierstrass approximation theorem, that there exists a monotone decreasing sequence of real polynomials $(P_n(t))$ that converge to $\varphi(t)$. As $\varphi(t)$ is bounded and the real polynomials $(P_n(t))$ are monotone decreasing, it follows that $P_n(A)\geq P_{n+1}(A)\geq\cdots$ is bounded monotone decreasing sequence of operators, thus the limit exists and we call it $\varphi(A)$ $(:=\lim P_n(A))$.

Since $P_n(t)$ are real polynomials, if $A$ is taken to be self-adjoint, then $P_n(A)$ are self-adjoint. Therefore $\lim P_n(A)$ is self-adjoint, and by definition $\varphi(A)$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: In lemma $1$, the dot on the left is multiplication of real valued functions, while on the right it is the composition of linear operators.

Comment: @SolubleFish: That would answer the question, and I believe you're correct. However, I don't see how the multiplication on the right is the composition of of linear operators. If you could explain this, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @SolubleFish: I've edit the post to include the definition of $\varphi(A)$ for $\varphi\in K[a,b]$. Perhaps this will make **Lemma 1** more clear. IMO, the author is trying to define a multiplicative property for functions of operators; such as, the function $\varphi(A)$. Thus I think the author is defining that operator on the right-hand-side to be what's on the left-hand-side.

Comment: @SolubleFish: Perhaps so, but I'm unfamiliar with so-called *morphism of algebras *. The right side multiplication is given by taking two non-negative monotone decreasing sequences $(P_n(t))$ and $(Q_n(t))$ for which $P_n(t)\searrow\varphi_1(t)$ and $Q_n(t)\searrow\varphi_2(t)$, so that $P_n(t)\cdot Q_n(t)\searrow\varphi_1(t)\cdot\varphi_2(t)$. Then noticing that $P_n(t)\cdot Q_n(t)\geq P_{n+1}(t)\cdot Q_{n+1}(t)$, which gives a bounded monotone decreasing sequence of operators $P_n(A)\cdot Q_n(A)\geq P_{n+1}(A)\cdot Q_{n+1}(A)$....

Comment: @SolubleFish:...Therefore the limit exists, and we call it $\varphi_1(A)\cdot\varphi_2(A)$ $(:=\lim P_n(A)\cdot Q_n(A))$. I just don't see where composition is coming in.

Comment: @SolubleFish: Yes! Functional Analysis by Eidelman-milman-tsolomitis, the first few pages of chapter 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of Chapter 7, in Functional Analysis (Eidelman; Milman & Tsolomitis) is building an [algebra homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_homomorphism) between the space of function spanned by $K[a,b]$ (which, in this case, is the set of function which can be written $f-g$ with $f,g\in K[ab]$) and the algebra of bounded linear operators.

To do this, they start with a morphism from the algebra of polynomial function. If $P$ is a polynomial function, then $P(A)$ is a (self-adjoint) operator. The mapping $P\mapsto P(A)$ has the property that $(P\cdot Q)(A) = P(A)\cdot Q(A)$ where the multiplication on the left if the usual multiplication of polynomials and the one on the right is the composition of linear operators. *This is where the composition enters the picture*.

Then, they have to do some work to show that this can be extended to any function in $K[a,b]$ and to differences of such functions, while preserving this property.

In the third remark after exercise $7.0.4$, where it is stated that $(\varphi_1\cdot \varphi_2)(A) = \varphi_1(A) \cdot \varphi_2(A)$ when $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\geq 0$, the dot on the right *is still the usual composition of linear operators*, because it is preserved when taking the limit : when $P_n\searrow \varphi_1$ and $Q_n\searrow \varphi_2$, we have $P_n(A)\to \varphi_1(A)$ strongly and $Q_n(A)\to \varphi_2(A)$. Therefore, $P_n(A)\cdot Q_n(A) \to \varphi_1(A) \cdot \varphi_2(A)$ (where the dot is still the usual composition). Now, because $P_n \cdot Q_n\searrow \varphi_1\cdot \varphi_2$, we also have $P_n(A)\cdot Q_n(A) \to (\varphi_1\cdot\varphi_2)(A)$. By unicity of the limit, we have :
$$(\varphi_1\cdot\varphi_2)(A) = \varphi_1(A) \cdot \varphi_2(A)$$

Comment: So the multiplication on the right, in your notation, is $P(A)\cdot Q(A)=P(Q(A))$, i.e. composition of linear operators?

Comment: I understand everything besides when you say, "the mapping $P\mapsto P(A)$ has the property that $(P\cdot Q)(A) = P(A)\cdot Q(A)$ where the multiplication on the left if the usual multiplication of polynomials and the one on the right is the composition of linear operators." I guess I don't know what "mapping $P\mapsto P(A)$" you're speaking of, and so I don't know why this mapping had that property as you say.

Comment: For instance, let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator and take $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ to be real polynomials, say, $P(x):=x^2+1$ and $Q(x)=3$. Then $(P(x)\cdot Q(x))(A)=(3x^2+3)(A)=3A^2+3I$, whereas 
$P(A)\circ Q(A)=(A^2+I)\circ(3I)=12I$. Clearly then $(P\cdot_\mathbb{R} Q)(A)\neq P(A)\circ Q(A)$ as you say. However, I know you must be correct, I just don't see how. Perhaps if you can point out what I did wrong in the example I gave, I can figure out what I'm thinking incorrectly about.

Comment: >So the multiplication on the right, in your notation, is P(A)⋅Q(A)=P(Q(A)), i.e. composition of linear operators? < No it is not ! $P(A)$ and $Q(A)$ are linear operators, so their composition is $P(A) \circ Q(A)$. When applied to a vector $x$, we have $P(A)\circ Q(A)(x) = P(A)(Q(A)(x))$

Comment: For your example, you have $P(A) \circ Q(A) = (A\circ A + I)\circ (3I) =3A\circ A + 3I$, so it works just fine

Comment: Thanks, I see now now $(P\cdot Q)(A) = P(A)\cdot Q(A)$. And so this holds for any polynomial and self-adjoint operator?

Comment: This holds for any polynomial and any linear operator defined over the whole Hilbert space (for unbounded operator, which are only defined over a dense subspace, it might be more complicated).

Comment: I see. This cleared up a lot, thank you!